# How to make a val inside the canvas function transfer outside

Tags: jquery, html, canvas

I tried a canvas element to make a game: you click the mouse and erase part of the picture, that is a val inside the function eventUp(), called effort, which means when you submit the result, what percentage of area you erased. But it looks like a local variable could not be used outside the addEventListener, how could I transfer it out and used in the ajax jquery？

```
<html>
 <head>
   <style>

#article {
    width:300px;
    float:left;
    padding:10px;        
    }
#aside{
    width:600px;
    height:500px;
    float:right;
    background-color:#eeeeee;
    padding:10px;
    }
  </style>

</head>

<body>
   <h1> It is a minion with one eye or two eyes</h1>

<div id="aside">
  <canvas id="mycanvas" width="600" height="500" style="border:1px solid #c3c3c3;">
  </canvas>
<script>
   var bodyStyle = document.body.style; 
   bodyStyle.mozUserSelect = 'none'; 
   bodyStyle.webkitUserSelect = 'none'; 


   var img = new Image(); 
   var canvas = document.querySelector('canvas'); 
       canvas.style.backgroundColor='transparent'; 
       canvas.style.position = 'absolute'; 
   var imgs = ['p_2.jpg','p_3.jpg','p_4.jpg','p_5.jpg','p_6.jpg','p_7.jpg','p_8.jpg','p_9.jpg','p_10.jpg','p_12.jpg'
       ,'p_12.jpg','p_13.jpg','p_14.jpg','p_15.jpg','p_16.jpg','p_17.jpg','p_18.jpg','p_19.jpg','p_20.jpg','p_21.jpg','p_22.jpg',
       'p_23.jpg','p_24.jpg','p_25.jpg','p_26.jpg']; 
   var num = Math.floor(Math.random()*24); 


   img.src = imgs[num]; 

   img.addEventListener('load', function(e) { 
          var ctx; 

          var w=600;
              h=500;
          var offsetX = canvas.offsetLeft, 
              offsetY = canvas.offsetTop; 
          var mousedown = false; 

        function layer(ctx) { 
               ctx.fillStyle = 'gray'; 
               ctx.fillRect(0, 0, w, h); 
               } 

        function eventDown(e){ 
               e.preventDefault(); 
               mousedown=true; 
               } 
        function eventUp(e){ 
               e.preventDefault(); 
               mousedown=false; 
               var data=ctx.getImageData(0,0,w,h).data;
               for(var i=0,j=0;i< data.length;i+=4){
                  if(data[i] && data[i+1] && data[i+2] && data[i+3]){
                  j++;
                  }
                var effort=j;
               }


               }           

        function eventMove(e){ 
              e.preventDefault(); 
              if(mousedown) { 
                if(e.changedTouches){ 
                  e=e.changedTouches[e.changedTouches.length-1]; 
                } 
               var x = (e.clientX + document.body.scrollLeft || e.pageX) - offsetX || 0, 
                   y = (e.clientY + document.body.scrollTop || e.pageY) - offsetY || 0; 
             with(ctx) { 
                 beginPath() 
             //arc(x, y, 10, 0, Math.PI * 2);//绘制圆点 
                 rect(x,y,50,50);
                 fill(); 
            } 
          } 
        } 

        canvas.width=w; 
        canvas.height=h; 
        canvas.style.backgroundImage='url('+img.src+')'; 
        ctx=canvas.getContext('2d'); 
        ctx.fillStyle='transparent'; 
        ctx.fillRect(0, 0, w, h);
        layer(ctx); 

        ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-out'; 

        canvas.addEventListener('touchstart', eventDown); 
        canvas.addEventListener('touchend', eventUp); 
        canvas.addEventListener('touchmove', eventMove); 
        canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', eventDown); 
        canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', eventUp); 
        canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', eventMove);  
    }); 

 </script>
   </div> 

      <script type="text/javascript">
           $(document).ready(function(){
                $("#submit").click(function(){

                      var taskid=num;
                      var name=$("#name").val();
                      var guessnum=$("#guessnum").val();

                      $.ajax({
                          type:"post",
                          url:"GameMysql.php",
                                     data:"name="+name+"&taskid="+taskid+"&guessnum="+guessnum+"&effort="+effort,
                         success:function(data){
                             $("#article").html(data);
                          }

                      });

                });
           });
  </script>
  <div id="article" >
      <form>
           name : <input type="text" name="name" id="name"/>
           </br>

       guessNum: <input type="number" name="guessnum"       id="guessnum"> 
           <input type="button" value="Send Guess" id="submit">

    </form>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just declare it outside, as a global variable, next to

```
<script>
   var bodyStyle = document.body.style;
```

So it will be accessible everywhere in your script.

You can also use `window.effort` from anywhere.

Note that using global variables is a bad practice and is discouraged, but that answers your question. You could also create one global object to store your variables, like :

`var allVariables = { effort : 0, otherVar : otherVal };` and access variables using `allVariables.effort`.

By the way, ajax parameters should be an object, not a string, so :

```
data:"name="+name+"&taskid="+taskid+"&guessnum="+guessnum+"&effort="+effort,
```

is incorrect, replace with :

```
 data:{name:name, taskid:taskid, guessnum:guessnum, effort:effort}
```

With the global object solution, you could even go :

```
data : allVariables
```

Comment: thanks for your patient advice, it works for me!  I once tried the ajax data:{name:name...} way, but it does not work, i do not know why. So then I transferred it to sting.

Comment: Your're welcome. Well, you also need to have the corresponding receiver. You programmed your PHP to expect and parse a string, now adapt it to expect and receive an object. That's how it's supposed to work : passing key-values directly, not strings to parse into key-values, which is just a waste of CPU time.